# How should I add list items and save it to local storage when making a Phonegap application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, local-storage

I'm making an app that logs the amount of hours you got at work and how much you made. 
Right now I'm doing this:

```
localStorage.cachedPay = madeamount.toFixed(2);
localStorage.cachedHours = houramount;
$madeamount.html(localStorage.cachedPay);
$houramount.html(localStorage.cachedHours);
```

So this is working but I'm just saving displaying two values in p tags, I need to be able to actually add the two values as a list item to the bottom of the page each time an instance is ended and save it to local storage so that they'll display on launch. What would be the best method for doing this? I would also like to be able to add up the total amounts for both logged values and display that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, and not using data structures:

```
var sumPay = 0;
var sumHours = 0;
for(var i = 0 ; i < localStorage.length; i++ ) {
    var strKey = localStorage.key(i);
    if(strKey.startsWith('myCachedPayPrefix_')) {
        var cachedPay = localStorage.getItem(strKey);
        sumPay = cachedPay; 
    }
    if(strKey.startsWith('myCachedHoursPrefix_')) {
        var cachedHours = localStorage.getItem(strKey);
        sumHours += cachedHours;
    }
}
```

Better: maintain an array, and use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to move that array in and out of  localStorage, but then you can manipulate it like a proper data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ended up using parsedpay = parseInt(localStorage["paycount"] + 1; then loaded it back with localStorage.paycount = parsedpay; to add it up and assign the names accordingly.